# jquery и зависимый размер изображений в блоке

Tags: jquery

Пишу скрипт: на странице есть изображения разных размеров, нужно, чтобы они увеличивались в зависимости от размера блока `.content`, размер блока может меняться в зависимости от разрешения экрана, либо при изменении размеров окна.

Если картинка меньше или равна `500px`, то ничего делать не нужно, если больше `500px`, то в зависимости от ширины `.content`, увеличивать её ширину на ширину `.content`.

Ещё одно условие: увеличивать картинки нужно, если размер `.content` больше, чем `570px`. Вообще размер картинки должен быть - это 570 + на сколько больше 570 размер `.content` (т.е. если `.content` больше 570, то картинки нужно увеличивать на дополнительное количество пикселей).
.news_img - это класс изображений.
Код:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( 
  function(){
    var widths = $(".content").css("width");
    $('img.news_img').each(function(){
  
    }) 
  } 
);
</script>
```

Не понимаю как обработать каждую картинку.

Comment: img.news_img {width:100%} в css чем не подошло?